# Does not update Elementary

Tags: updates, appcenter

Last week, i was updating Elementary OS, suddenly my internet connection disconnected. After connecting the internet, i saw was left 511kb of updating. After click update button, was not updated. When restart my pc always views on the app center. I tried update from command line using `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` but did not work.

[image: App Center]

How do i update my os?

`sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`:

[image: terminal output]
[image: eterminal output 2]

**I am sorry for my Turkish outputs. Please use  translate.**

```
samet@samet-X540LA:~$ ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
baitsart-ubuntu-voice-commands-bionic.list       microsoft-prod.list       vscode.list
baitsart-ubuntu-voice-commands-bionic.list.save  microsoft-prod.list.save  vscode.list.save
```

Comment: Please update your question adding the terminal output after executing `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`.

Comment: OOkey! I added.

Comment: execute on terminal: `ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d/` and copy paste the output (it's easier to read than a picture). I suspect there's something wrong with some apps you've installed or ppas that you have added.

Comment: This worked for me thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh god, finally, i solved the issue.
When i execute `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` on terminal, gets following output:

```
samet@samet-X540LA:~$ sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
Aynı:  1 http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Aynı:  2 http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease                                              
Aynı:  3 http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease                                            
Aynı:  4 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease                                               
Aynı:  5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease                                               
Aynı:  6 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/18.04/prod bionic InRelease     
Paket listeleri okunuyor... Bitti                     
Bağımlılık ağacı oluşturuluyor       
Durum bilgisi okunuyor... Bitti      
1 paket yükseltilebilir. Bu paketi görmek için 'apt list --upgradable' komutunu çalıştırın.
N: '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' dizinindeki 'baitsart-ubuntu-voice-commands-bionic.list.save' dosyası geçersiz bir dosya uzantısı olduğu için yok sayılıyor
N: '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' dizinindeki 'vscode.list.save' dosyası geçersiz bir dosya uzantısı olduğu için yok sayılıyor
N: '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' dizinindeki 'microsoft-prod.list.save' dosyası geçersiz bir dosya uzantısı olduğu için yok sayılıyor
Paket listeleri okunuyor... Bitti
Bağımlılık ağacı oluşturuluyor       
Durum bilgisi okunuyor... Bitti      
Yükseltme hesaplanıyor... Bitti
Aşağıdaki paketlerin mevcut durumları korunacak:
  libodbc1
0 paket yükseltilecek, 0 yeni paket kurulacak, 0 paket kaldırılacak ve 1 paket yükseltilmeyecek.
```

`libodbc1`?? I thinked a secret was in `libodbc1` and i executed `sudo apt install libodbc1`. Finally issue is solved.